# Caught and declared exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception

In Java, if I declare and caught an exception, can I handle the exception in a caller anyway? Or it needs not to be caught to handle it by caller?

```
class A {
  void first() throws Exception { 
    try {
      throw new Exception("my exception")
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.message("Error in first()", e.getCouse)
      throw e
    }
  }
}

class B {
  Result second(A a) {
    try {
      a.first()
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.message("Caught in B class", e.message)
      return new Result(result: null, error: e.message)
    }
  }

  second(A a)
}
```

Comment: If you have declared the `Exception` in your `throws` declaration, then the caller **MUST** handle it (even though it can possibly be never thrown), else they will get a compilation error.

Comment: It depends on the exception type, the method signature and a few other things.  Please give us an example, including the declaration of the exception class (if it is a custom exception.)

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. If you catch an exception in method A (not re-throwing something), that tells A's caller that A successfully finished its job. So to A's caller, everything is normal and not exceptional, and no need to handle an exception. So, please elaborate on your use case.

Comment: Catch to log in a service and throw to caller in contrller so caller can return message to RESTful API user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply rethrow the exception you've caught (obviously the surrounding method has to permit this via its signature etc.). The exception will maintain the original stack trace.

```
catch (WhateverException e) {
    throw e;
}
```

You can also wrap the exception in another one AND keep the original stack trace by passing in the Exception as a Throwable as the cause parameter:

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     throw new YourOwnException(e);
}
```